# "for each in" standard output bash

Tags: bash, foreach

I am looking to generate an output file that contains the result of the following command:

```
cd /path/to/files/; for each in *; do cat $each; echo "######_NEW_FILE_######"; done
```

I have tried:

```
cd /path/to/files/; for each in *; do cat $each; echo "######_NEW_FILE_######"; > output.txt; done
```

This generates the file, but it is blank. I have also tried:

```
cd /path/to/files/; for each in *; do cat $each; echo "######_NEW_FILE_######"; done; >output.txt
```

This generates a file that is way too big. This is not what I am looking for. 
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Too big?, So you don't want all the content of those files in this file?

Comment: ...I mean, there are some obvious lack-of-quoting bugs, but it'd help if you described what exactly "too big" means in this context.

Comment: Do you want only the result of echo in the file or the content of those files + the echo result?

Comment: krzyk- I am looking for both the content and the echo. When I type the command without the > output.txt, I see in the terminal what I expect is the output. I compared that with what was being generated with the > output.txt and it seemed disproportionate. For example, the output was about 250 GB before I stopped it- way more than what was in all of the files I was concatenating!

Comment: @Rob, ...if you're getting more content than the literal size of the files, you'll want to look into (1) whether any of those files are actually symlinks you aren't dereferencing when measuring size, *or* (2) whether any of those files have names which can be expanded as globs. If you have a file named `*`, for instance, then `cat $each` would re-`cat` **every other file**. If you had a file named `* hello *`, then trying to `cat $each` on that file would re-`cat` *every other file* **twice**. This is part of why correctly quoting in your scripts is important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have a redirection in place for a block of commands, without the performance impact and other side effects involved in a subshell, put it in braces:

```
{
  cd /path/to/files/; for each in *; do cat "$each"; echo "######_NEW_FILE_######"; done 
} >output.txt
```

...as a one-liner, be sure to put a `;` before the closing brace:

```
{ cd /path/to/files/; for each in *; do cat "$each"; echo "######_NEW_FILE_######"; done; } >output.txt
```

---

By the way, note that it's `cat "$each"`, not `cat $each`. If you have a file created with `touch '*'`, you'd be doubling your output size otherwise.

---

That said, this is indeed *very nearly* identical to:

```
cd /path/to/files/; for each in *; do cat "$each"; echo "######_NEW_FILE_######"; done >output.txt
```

...for which the `>output.txt` applies to the `for` loop (and only the loop). The difference, then, is that the `{ ... }` approach also redirects any stdout from the `cd` command (for which there should be none, unless you have it redefined with a shell function wrapper or similar).

That is to say:

```
# this does not redirect the header
cd /path/to/files; echo "header"; for each in *; do cat "$each"; done >output

# this does not redirect the header or the loop
cd /path/to/files; echo "header"; for each in *; do cat "$each"; done; echo footer >output

# this redirects everything
{ cd /path/to/files; echo "header"; for each in *; do cat "$each"; done; echo footer; } >output
```

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
... echo $each"######_NEW_FILE_######"; > output.txt
                                      ^---
```

You terminate the `echo` with that `;`, making `> output.txt` a statement completely independent of the echo.

You want

```
... echo '...' > output.txt; etc...
                           ^---note
```

Answer (score 0):

The semicolon that follows `done` ends the statement, which means that the redirect isn't associated with any command.

Lose the last `;` and it should work.